# How to use OAuth Module (Twitter) with Kohana3 - KohanaPHP

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, kohana, kohana-3

I am trying to use the [OAuth Library for Kohana](https://github.com/kohana/oauth) with Kohana3. I already used The [EpiTwitter Class](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/twitter-php-oauth.html) with Kohana2, but there was a good Documentation. Now trying to get started with this OAuth Class.

I already implemented the authorization and so i get an acces token, access token secret and the request token verifier.

But I dont know now, how to get the **account/verify_credentials** or any other request to the twitter api. Because there is no documentation and I can't find an "Request" function.

Should I write my own Request class or function? Or is there any but I cant see it? If yes, how to use?

Thanks a lot!

Ahmet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the [Twitter demo controller](https://github.com/shadowhand/apis/blob/demos/twitter/classes/controller/twitter/demo.php) (in the "demos" branch) will help you?

You can run the demos locally by installing the git repo as a submodule, checking out the "demos" branch, and then going to `http://your_kohana_install/twitter_demo`, it will give you a nice big table with all the code used and the responses. You'll need an API key before anything will work though.

Comment: I didn't know that there is a twitter Class for this OAuth Class! Thank you :) Now everything is working like it should ;)